# Gtk.CellRendererText with format

Tags: gtk, vala

I would like to write a custom CellRenderer that formats it's content. Instead of displaying `-905.65000` it should display `-905.65 €`. I already could achieve this with a `Gtk.TreeCellDataFunc` but it would be more elegant with a custom CellRenderer.

Following code gives a segmentation fault:

```
class CellRendererTextFormat : Gtk.CellRendererText {
    public new string text {
      get { return text; }
      set {
        char[] a = new char[16];
        text = double.parse(value).format(a,"%-.2f €");
      }
    }

    public CellRendererTextFormat () {
        GLib.Object ();
    }
}
```

How should i do it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1) `text` is assigned the memory for `a`, which is freed. You need to assign it to memory that is durable beyond the scope of the `set`.

2) `value` is now a string (because you can only assign properties values of the same type). Do you actually have strings, or did you put in that `parse` just to make it work?

Instead:

```
class CellRendererEuroValue : Gtk.CellRendererText {
    char[] euro_str = new char[16];
    private double _euro_value;
    public double euro_value {
      get { return _euro_value; }
      set {
        _euro_value = value;
        value.format(euro_str,"%-.2f €");
        text = (string) euro_str;
      }
    }

    public CellRendererTextFormat () {
        GLib.Object ();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, value is a string that i need to parse into a double. You changed the variable `text` by `euro_value`, i actually wanted to override the `text` parameter from `Gtk.CellRendererText`, would you do it otherwise to have `euro_value` getting displayed?

Comment: You were using `new` so it wouldn't have been overridden anyway. You should parse outside the property setter so you can handle errors. Edited the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. Just needed to add "euro_value" to my columns attributes... ^^"